# How can I achive side by side text views like shown in image in android? Which layout has to be used?

Tags: android

[image: The image shown is some flowlayout.]

How do I achieve this, using layouts, all I am able to do is make them flow horizontally or vertically using listview. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using relative or grid layout and maybe some margin and weight logic to get something similar to a flexbox as in CSS.

or

you can use this nice flexbox library for android if you want to save yourself some time : https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout

Comment: Upvoting the FlexboxLayout portion of this answer

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView) with a horizontal [StaggeredGridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager) with 4 rows.

You can set it with:

```
StaggeredGridLayoutManager layoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(4, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

The tags are a separate list from the days.